# How to assign KeyboardEvent?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I tried to make something on @keydown. But finally I got error:

```
    Type 'Event | KeyboardEvent' is not assignable to type 'KeyboardEvent'.
      Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'KeyboardEvent': altKey, charCode, code, ctrlKey, and 17 more.
```

```
@keydown="(event) => handleInputFocus(index, event)"
```

```
const handleInputFocus = (id: number, e: KeyboardEvent) => {
...
```

Comment: Did you try to use evt instead of event as parameter?

Comment: @Wimanicesir, my bad. I updated error message and have almost the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript keyboard event : argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEvent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261639/typescript-keyboard-event-argument-of-type-event-is-not-assignable-to-parame)

Answer (score 1):

Try please.

```
@keydown="handleInputFocus(event, index)"
```

or

```
 @keydown="handleInputFocus($event, index)"
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't help